# Find common "characters" in 2 given strings (rev1)

Tags: java, algorithm

I would like a review of:

- Correctness, especially around edge/corner cases
- Efficiency
- Readability and/or style
- Appropriate use of Java idioms and data structures

In particular:

- Have I missed typical idioms/patterns useful to solving the problem?
- Could I have reused existing/popular framework/library code?

Less interesting to me:

- Feedback on the test harness logic in `main()` (I could have used JUnit)

[A glance at program output from online execution](http://ideone.com/nqc3Qo)

I have rewritten the code below, including feedback, as Rev2 @ [Find common "characters" in 2 given strings (rev2)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106512/find-common-characters-in-2-given-strings-rev2), follow the link to look at the updated version

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
class CommonCharacters {
  @SuppressWarnings("boxing")
  private static String commonCharactersOf(String string1, String string2) {
    // Requirement
    //
    // Always return lowercase versions of common characters. e.g.:
    //
    // OK: (a, a) -> a
    // OK: (a, A) -> a
    // OK: (A, A) -> a
    // No: (A, A) -> A
    // No: (aA, aA) -> aA
    //
    // Requirement
    //
    // Return common characters joined in a String, preserving the order in
    // which they appeared in the longest argument, or in the first argument if
    // the arguments are of the same length.
    //
    // Requirement
    //
    // Handle "characters" (i.e. code points) outside the Basic Multilingual
    // Plane (BMP), including characters from Supplementary Planes.
    // There should be no `char' or `Character' based "false positives". i.e.:
    //
    // String string1 = "\uD835\uDC00", string2 = "\uD835\uDC01";
    //
    // string1 and string2 share no characters in the intended acceptation of
    // "character".
    String shortestArgument, longestArgument;
    if (string1.length() < string2.length()) {
      shortestArgument = string1;
      longestArgument = string2;
    } else {
      shortestArgument = string2;
      longestArgument = string1;
    }
    // @formatter:off
    Set<Integer> codePointsSeen =
        shortestArgument.codePoints()
        .boxed()
        .map(Character::toLowerCase)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    List<Integer> codePointsInCommon = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Iterator<Integer> iterator = longestArgument.codePoints()
                                                     .distinct()
                                                     .iterator();
         iterator.hasNext() &&
         codePointsInCommon.size() < codePointsSeen.size();) {
    // @formatter:on
      Integer codePoint = iterator.next();
      int lowerCaseCodePoint = Character.toLowerCase(codePoint);
      if (codePointsSeen.contains(lowerCaseCodePoint)) {
        codePointsInCommon.add(lowerCaseCodePoint);
      }
    }
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (Integer codePoint : codePointsInCommon) {
      stringBuilder.appendCodePoint(codePoint);
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
  }
  @SuppressWarnings("boxing")
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // @formatter:off
    String[][] testArgumentsAndExpectedValues = {
        { ""                     , ""                  , ""             },
        { "a"                    , ""                  , ""             },
        { ""                     , "a"                 , ""             },
        { "aa"                   , ""                  , ""             },
        { ""                     , "aa"                , ""             },
        { "a"                    , "a"                 , "a"            },
        { "aa"                   , "b"                 , ""             },
        { "b"                    , "aa"                , ""             },
        { "ab"                   , "ba"                , "ab"           },
        { "aba"                  , "ab"                , "ab"           },
        { "aba"                  , "ba"                , "ab"           },
        { "aba"                  , "aab"               , "ab"           },
        { "a"                    , "A"                 , "a"            },
        { "A"                    , "a"                 , "a"            },
        { "A"                    , "A"                 , "a"            },
        { "ab"                   , "AB"                , "ab"           },
        { "AB"                   , "ab"                , "ab"           },
        { "aB"                   , "Ab"                , "ab"           },
        { "aB"                   , "Ba"                , "ab"           },
        { "aB"                   , "Ba"                , "ab"           },
        { "a"                    , "\uD835\uDC1A"      , ""             },
        { "\uD835\uDC1A"         , "\uD835\uDC1A"      , "\uD835\uDC1A" },
        { "\uD835\uDC00"         , "\uD835\uDC00"      , "\uD835\uDC00" },
        { "\uD835\uDC1A"         , "\uD835\uDC00"      , ""             },
        { "\uD835\uDC00"         , "\uD835\uDC01"      , ""             },
        { "\uD801\uDC2B"         , "\uD801\uDC2B"      , "\uD801\uDC2B" },
        { "\uD801\uDC03"         , "\uD801\uDC03"      , "\uD801\uDC2B" },
        { "\uD801\uDC2B"         , "\uD801\uDC03"      , "\uD801\uDC2B" },
        { "\uD83D\uDE80"         , "\uD83D\uDE80"      , "\uD83D\uDE80" },
        { "a"                    , "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" , "a"            },
        // The last test should still work, and work fast, with a second
        // argument string starting with "a" and ending _many_ characters later
        // The last test values doe not test it, but illustrate the scenario
    };
    int maximumTestArgumentLength =
        Arrays.stream(testArgumentsAndExpectedValues)
              .flatMap(testValues -> Arrays.stream(testValues)
                                           .limit(2))
              .mapToInt(String::length)
              .max()
              .getAsInt();
    // @formatter:on
    int maximumQuotedTestArgumentLength = maximumTestArgumentLength + 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < testArgumentsAndExpectedValues.length; i++) {
      String[] currentTestValues = testArgumentsAndExpectedValues[i];
      String string1 = currentTestValues[0];
      String string2 = currentTestValues[1];
      String expectedResult = currentTestValues[2];
      String actualResult = commonCharactersOf(string1, string2);
      boolean testSuccessful = expectedResult.equals(actualResult);
      if (testSuccessful) {
        // continue; // TODO: uncomment to filter out successful tests
      }
      Function<String, String> quoteString = s -> '"' + s + '"';
      // @formatter:off
      String outputFormat = "%2d) "
                          + "%5s: "
                          + "(%-" + maximumQuotedTestArgumentLength + "s"
                          + " , "
                          + "%-" + maximumQuotedTestArgumentLength + "s)"
                          + " -> "
                          + "%s "
                          + "(%s)"
                          + "%n";
      System.out.printf(outputFormat,
                        i,
                        testSuccessful ? "Success" : "Failure",
                        quoteString.apply(string1),
                        quoteString.apply(string2),
                        quoteString.apply(actualResult),
                        quoteString.apply(expectedResult));
      // @formatter:on
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "common characters"?  Sequence(s) of characters?  Duplicates are allowed?

Comment: No duplicates. (Look at my sample test cases...)

Comment: Your cases are quite limited.  "aabccc" and "aaccc" gives "aaccc" or "ccc"?

Comment: "aabccc", "aaccc" -> "ac"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like that you use Streams.  But I think you should use even more of their functionality:

- You could have used `map` to get the lower case for `longestArgument`.  Or maybe it would have been simpler to just use `longestArgument.toLowerCase()`, and same for `shortestArgument`.
- You use `distinct()` to remove duplicate, but you could have gotten rid of the main for-loop entirely by also using `filter(...)` where the filter uses a predicate built from the values in `shortestArgument`.
- For the final output, you can use `codePointStream.toArray()` to create an `int[]` and then use [`String(codePointArray, 0, codePointArray.length)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-int:A-int-int-).  You could instead use `intStream.collect(...)` to perform a reduction which would fill and return a `StringBuilder`, but it would end up quite ugly.

You spend many lines defining the shortest/longest strings, but I don't see how that is relevant.  You could just assign any string to any of those and the algorithm would still work.

I might have written the program a bit differently.  I would define a function that takes a string and returns the lower case version with no duplicate, in the same order, as an `IntStream`.  I would apply that function at the start on both input strings.  And then apply `filter` on one of them, with the predicate built from the values of the other.