# Find common "characters" in 2 given strings (rev2)

Tags: java, algorithm

Could you help me further improve this code, which includes some feedback from this site already ([Find common "characters" in 2 given strings (rev1)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106473/))?

I have rewritten the code below, including feedback, as Rev3 @ [Find common “characters” in 2 given strings (rev3)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106514/find-common-characters-in-2-given-strings-rev3).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class CommonCharacters2 {
  private static String commonCharactersOf(String string1, String string2) {
    // Requirement
    //
    // Always return lowercase versions of common characters. e.g.:
    //
    // OK: (a, a) -> a; OK: (a, A) -> a; OK: (A, A) -> a
    // No: (a, A) -> a; No: (A, A) -> A; No: (aA, aA) -> aA;
    //
    // Requirement
    //
    // Return common characters joined in a String, preserving the order in
    // which they appeared in the longest argument, or in the first argument if
    // the arguments are of the same length.
    //
    // Requirement
    //
    // Handle "characters" (i.e. code points) outside the Basic Multilingual
    // Plane (BMP), including characters from Supplementary Planes.
    // There should be no `char' or `Character' based "false positives". e.g.:
    //
    // String string1 = "\uD835\uDC00", string2 = "\uD835\uDC01";
    // string1 and string2 share no characters in the intended acceptation of
    // "character".
    String shorterArgument, longerArgument;
    if (string1.length() < string2.length()) {
      shorterArgument = string1;
      longerArgument = string2;
    } else {
      shorterArgument = string2;
      longerArgument = string1;
    }
    // @formatter:off
    Set<Integer> codePointsOfShorterArgument =
        shorterArgument.codePoints()
        .boxed()
        .map(Character::toLowerCase)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    List<Integer> codePointsInCommon = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] resultCodePoints =
        longerArgument.codePoints()
                      .distinct()
                      .filter($ -> codePointsInCommon.size()
                                   < codePointsOfShorterArgument.size())
                      .map(Character::toLowerCase)
                      .filter(i -> codePointsOfShorterArgument.contains(i))
                      .toArray();
    return new String(resultCodePoints, 0, resultCodePoints.length);
  }
  @Parameters(name = "({0}, {1}) -> {2}")
  public static Collection<String[]> data() {
    return Arrays.asList(new String[][] {
        { ""             , ""                  , ""             },
        { "a"            , ""                  , ""             },
        { ""             , "a"                 , ""             },
        { "aa"           , ""                  , ""             },
        { ""             , "aa"                , ""             },
        { "a"            , "a"                 , "a"            },
        { "aa"           , "b"                 , ""             },
        { "b"            , "aa"                , ""             },
        { "ab"           , "ba"                , "ab"           },
        { "aba"          , "ab"                , "ab"           },
        { "aba"          , "ba"                , "ab"           },
        { "aba"          , "aab"               , "ab"           },
        { "a"            , "A"                 , "a"            },
        { "A"            , "a"                 , "a"            },
        { "A"            , "A"                 , "a"            },
        { "ab"           , "AB"                , "ab"           },
        { "AB"           , "ab"                , "ab"           },
        { "aB"           , "Ab"                , "ab"           },
        { "aB"           , "Ba"                , "ab"           },
        { "aB"           , "Ba"                , "ab"           },
        { "abc"          , "ac"                , "ac"           },
        { "abc"          , "ca"                , "ac"           },
        { "abc"          , "cba"               , "abc"          },
        { "a"            , "\uD835\uDC1A"      , ""             },
        { "\uD835\uDC1A" , "\uD835\uDC1A"      , "\uD835\uDC1A" },
        { "\uD835\uDC00" , "\uD835\uDC00"      , "\uD835\uDC00" },
        { "\uD835\uDC1A" , "\uD835\uDC00"      , ""             },
        { "\uD835\uDC00" , "\uD835\uDC01"      , ""             },
        { "\uD801\uDC2B" , "\uD801\uDC2B"      , "\uD801\uDC2B" },
        { "\uD801\uDC03" , "\uD801\uDC03"      , "\uD801\uDC2B" },
        { "\uD801\uDC2B" , "\uD801\uDC03"      , "\uD801\uDC2B" },
        { "\uD83D\uDE80" , "\uD83D\uDE80"      , "\uD83D\uDE80" },
        { "a"            , "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" , "a"            },
        // The last test should still work, and work fast, with a second
        // argument string starting with "a" and ending _many_ characters later
        // The last test values doe not test it, but illustrate the scenario
      });
  }
  // @formatter:on
  private String string1;
  private String string2;
  private String expected;
  public CommonCharacters2(String string1, String string2, String expected) {
    this.string1 = string1;
    this.string2 = string2;
    this.expected = expected;
  }
  @Test
  public void test() {
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, commonCharactersOf(string1, string2));
  }
}
```

JUnit test results screenshot, useful to glance at what the hexadecimal literals encode, in terms of surrogate pairs:

[image: JUnit test results screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this piece:

> ```
> List<Integer> codePointsInCommon = new ArrayList<>();
> int[] resultCodePoints =
>     longerArgument.codePoints()
>                   .distinct()
>                   .filter($ -> codePointsInCommon.size()
>                                < codePointsOfShorterArgument.size())
>                   .map(Character::toLowerCase)
>                   .filter(i -> codePointsOfShorterArgument.contains(i))
>                   .toArray();
> ```

`codePointsInCommon` is never written to.
As such, the filter can be rewritten as:

```
.filter($ -> !codePointsOfShorterArgument.isEmpty())
```

However, it's actually a pointless filter, it can be simply dropped.

---

This filter can be simplified using a method reference:

> ```
>   .filter(i -> codePointsOfShorterArgument.contains(i))
> ```

Like this:

```
.filter(codePointsOfShorterArgument::contains)
```

Comment: Well spotted. It's a copy/paste mistake. I will accept your answer, edit and repost. I'll show in the next rev what I meant there.

Comment: You will see in the next rev that it is not a pointless filter once amended.