# Find common “characters” in 2 given strings (rev4)

Tags: java, algorithm

Could you help me further improve this code, which includes some feedback from this site already [Find common “characters” in 2 given strings (rev3)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106514/find-common-characters-in-2-given-strings-rev3)?

**What** has changed since version 3:

I re-implemented the short-circuiting of scanning the longest string argument via a loop, in the absence of `.takeWhile` in the Java version I am coding in (i.e. Java 8).

**Why** I'd like a review:

I would be more satisfied with a Stream-based solution with no intermediate iterator, or a more natural/idiomatic way of formulating the mandate of stopping the consumption of the stream once it can never yield additional shared characters, as all characters in the other string have already been seen.

I have rewritten the code below, including feedback, as [Find common “characters” in 2 given strings (rev5)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106538/find-common-characters-in-2-given-strings-rev5).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class CommonCharacters4 {
  @SuppressWarnings("boxing")
  private static String commonCharactersOf(String string1, String string2) {
    // Requirement
    //
    // Always return lowercase versions of common characters. e.g.:
    //
    // OK: (a, a) -> a; OK: (a, A) -> a; OK: (A, A) -> a
    // No: (a, A) -> a; No: (A, A) -> A; No: (aA, aA) -> aA;
    //
    // Requirement
    //
    // Return common characters joined in a String, preserving the order in
    // which they appeared in the longest argument, or in the first argument if
    // the arguments are of the same length.
    //
    // Requirement
    //
    // Handle "characters" (i.e. code points) outside the Basic Multilingual
    // Plane (BMP), including characters from Supplementary Planes.
    // There should be no `char' or `Character' based "false positives". e.g.:
    //
    // String string1 = "\uD835\uDC00", string2 = "\uD835\uDC01";
    // string1 and string2 share no characters in the intended acceptation of
    // "character".
    String shorterArgument, longerArgument;
    if (string1.length() < string2.length()) {
      shorterArgument = string1;
      longerArgument = string2;
    } else {
      shorterArgument = string2;
      longerArgument = string1;
    }
    // @formatter:off
    Set<Integer> shorterArgumentCodePoints =
        shorterArgument.codePoints()
                       .map(Character::toLowerCase)
                       .boxed()
                       .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    List<Integer> codePointsInCommon = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<Integer> longerArgumentCodePoints =
        longerArgument.codePoints()
                      .map(Character::toLowerCase)
                      .distinct()
                      .iterator();
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    while (longerArgumentCodePoints.hasNext()
           && codePointsInCommon.size() < shorterArgumentCodePoints.size()) {
      Integer codePoint = longerArgumentCodePoints.next();
      if (shorterArgumentCodePoints.contains(codePoint)) {
        codePointsInCommon.add(codePoint);
        stringBuilder.appendCodePoint(codePoint);
      }
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
  }
  @Parameters(name = "({0}, {1}) -> {2}")
  public static Collection<String[]> data() {
    return Arrays.asList(new String[][] {
      // @formatter:off
      { ""             , ""                  , ""             },
      { "a"            , ""                  , ""             },
      { ""             , "a"                 , ""             },
      { "aa"           , ""                  , ""             },
      { ""             , "aa"                , ""             },
      { "a"            , "a"                 , "a"            },
      { "aa"           , "b"                 , ""             },
      { "b"            , "aa"                , ""             },
      { "ab"           , "ba"                , "ab"           },
      { "aba"          , "ab"                , "ab"           },
      { "aba"          , "ba"                , "ab"           },
      { "aba"          , "aab"               , "ab"           },
      { "a"            , "A"                 , "a"            },
      { "A"            , "a"                 , "a"            },
      { "A"            , "A"                 , "a"            },
      { "ab"           , "AB"                , "ab"           },
      { "AB"           , "ab"                , "ab"           },
      { "aB"           , "Ab"                , "ab"           },
      { "aB"           , "Ba"                , "ab"           },
      { "aB"           , "Ba"                , "ab"           },
      { "abc"          , "ac"                , "ac"           },
      { "abc"          , "ca"                , "ac"           },
      { "abc"          , "cba"               , "abc"          },
      { "a"            , "\uD835\uDC1A"      , ""             },
      { "\uD835\uDC1A" , "\uD835\uDC1A"      , "\uD835\uDC1A" },
      { "\uD835\uDC00" , "\uD835\uDC00"      , "\uD835\uDC00" },
      { "\uD835\uDC1A" , "\uD835\uDC00"      , ""             },
      { "\uD835\uDC00" , "\uD835\uDC01"      , ""             },
      { "\uD801\uDC2B" , "\uD801\uDC2B"      , "\uD801\uDC2B" },
      { "\uD801\uDC03" , "\uD801\uDC03"      , "\uD801\uDC2B" },
      { "\uD801\uDC2B" , "\uD801\uDC03"      , "\uD801\uDC2B" },
      { "\uD83D\uDE80" , "\uD83D\uDE80"      , "\uD83D\uDE80" },
      { "a"            , "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" , "a"            },
      // The last test should still work, and work fast, with a second
      // argument string starting with "a" and ending _many_ characters later
      // The last test values doe not test it, but illustrate the scenario
      // @formatter:on
    });
  }
  private String string1;
  private String string2;
  private String expected;
  public CommonCharacters4(String string1, String string2, String expected) {
    this.string1 = string1;
    this.string2 = string2;
    this.expected = expected;
  }
  @org.junit.Test
  public void test() {
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, commonCharactersOf(string1, string2));
  }
}
```

JUnit test results screenshot, useful to glance at what the hexadecimal literals encode, in terms of surrogate pairs:

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend that you don't be too quick in accepting an answer if you want more feedback, instead of continuously getting an answer -> post new question -> get answer -> post new question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The elements of `codePointsInCommon` are never used; the only thing of importance is the number of elements in the list. You can thus replace the list with an `int`, or better yet, stop iterating early using `limit`:

```
Set<Integer> shorterArgumentCodePoints =
        shorterArgument.codePoints()
                       .map(Character::toLowerCase)
                       .boxed()
                       .collect(Collectors.toSet());
IntStream commonCodePoints =
        longerArgument.codePoints()
                      .map(Character::toLowerCase)
                      .distinct()
                      .filter(shorterArgumentCodePoints::contains)
                      .limit(shorterArgumentCodePoints.size());
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
commonCodePoints.forEach(result::appendCodePoint);
return result.toString();
```

Comment: @Maroloccio could you please have a look at [this link](http://pastebin.com/49ci7RkZ) and let me know if you think that would work? If so I'll edit it into the question.

Comment: I think it's an awesome suggestion, actually. Just join the limit to the first stream operation though. You would have the best code for this exercise so far.